# execution of a command (unexpected behaviour)

Tags: unix

`ps -ef | grep "someprocess"` output lines contain :

```
.........................someprocess
.........................ps -ef | grep "someprocess"
```

Can somebody explain how this gets executed??

If I am checking for a process that is running or not it will allways come as running since
`ps -ef | grep "someprocess"` will always be there
Of course I know that I can do `ps -ef | grep "someprocess" | grep -v 'grep'`

But I  want to know the process of execution of the above to be clear. why do I get the line that I just executed (`ps -ef | grep "someprocess`") searching for a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this blog post](http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=110):

> Why does `grep` show itself? Because the pipe is created by the shell an instant before `ps` is executed so when the latter searches for all the loaded processes even `grep` is found.

Comment: @mukesh: Welcome to StackOverflow! [Thanks, I got it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) is best expressed as a green tick mark next to the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Or use

```
pgrep -fl somepattern
```

that will not show the pgrep process by default

Similarly, pkill will not kill itself :)